# Return Selected Value From Dropdown and Checkbox Using Ipywidgets

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I currently have the following code:

```
from ipywidgets import Checkbox, Dropdown, interact, widgets

def locate_customer_name(list_of_values: list) -> list:
    db_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow], description='Color:', value=None)
    unknown_checkbox = widgets.Checkbox(
        value=False, description='Unable to locate Color In list', disabled=False, indent=False
    )

    @interact(db_dropdown_values=db_dropdown, lost_checkbox=unknown_checkbox)
    def _core_func(db_dropdown_values, lost_checkbox):
        dropdown_selection = db_dropdown.value
        checkbox = unknown_checkbox.value
        button = widgets.Button(description='Confirm')
        out = widgets.Output()
        def _on_button_clicked(dropdown_select, checkbox):
            with out:
                print(dropdown_select, checkbox)
        display(button, out)
        button.on_click(_on_button_clicked(dropdown_selection, checkbox))
```

What I am looking to do is return the values selected in the _on_button_click function (e.g. dropdown_select and checkbox). For now, it seems like I am only able to print those variables out. How would I return them, so I can use them as inputs to another function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how would you return the values from an event like the click of a button. What I usually do is to create a state class to store the values and use in the following function, something like:

```py
from functools import partial
from dataclasses import dataclass
from ipywidgets import Checkbox, Dropdown, interact, widgets

@dataclass
class State:
    color: str = None
    located: bool = False
        
state = State()

def locate_customer_name(list_of_values: list) -> list:
    db_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow'], description='Color:', value=None)
    unknown_checkbox = widgets.Checkbox(
        value=False, description='Unable to locate Color In list', disabled=False, indent=False
    )

    @interact(db_dropdown_values=db_dropdown, lost_checkbox=unknown_checkbox)
    def _core_func(db_dropdown_values, lost_checkbox):
        dropdown_selection = db_dropdown.value
        checkbox = unknown_checkbox.value
        button = widgets.Button(description='Confirm')

        def _on_button_clicked(dropdown_select, checkbox, event):
            state.color = dropdown_select
            state.located = checkbox
        
        callback = partial(
            _on_button_clicked,
            dropdown_selection, 
            checkbox
        )
        
        button.on_click(callback)
        
        display(button)
        
locate_customer_name(['Briana', 'Mr White'])
```

PS: I'm using functools to add the arguments to the on_click callback. Check [this issue](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2202) if you want more information about it.

Comment: Running your above code, what do I need to call to access the values selected in the dropdown?

Comment: You will be able to get the data by calling the `state` property.